# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 building nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Recently I was trying to get a Ruby on Rails project running on macOS Ventura (Apple M1 Silicon) and was running into a problem with building the `nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure` gem.

The build error:

```
make "DESTDIR="
compiling init.c
compiling nokogiri_decrypt_with_key.c
compiling nokogiri_encrypt_with_key.c
compiling nokogiri_helpers_set_attribute_id.c
compiling nokogiri_init.c
compiling nokogiri_sign.c
compiling nokogiri_verify_with.c
compiling options.c
compiling shutdown.c
compiling util.c
linking shared-object nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_noko_xml_document_pin_node", referenced from:
      _decrypt_with_key in nokogiri_decrypt_with_key.o
  "_noko_xml_node_wrap", referenced from:
      _get_id in nokogiri_helpers_set_attribute_id.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this problem is:

1. Make sure you have installed `brew install libxmlsec1 pkg-config`
2. Run `bundle config build.nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure --with-ldflags="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup"` (Source: https://github.com/instructure/nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure/issues/15)

You should now be able to `bundle install` and build `nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure`